# problem with `glob` function in perl

Tags: perl, glob

I want to get a list of all the files whose name looks like : `$res_dir/$line/$fub_name*.istf`

meaning: in directory `$dir` in sub directory `$line` a file that starts with `$name` and ends with `.istf`.

each sub directory contains only 1 such file, but there are many sub directories. I've written this:

```
foreach $line (@arr){
    chomp ($line);
    $new_istf = glob ("$res_dir/$line/$fub_name*.istf");
    do something...
```

but it doesn't give me all the files, but only half of them. when I added the fallowing debug code:

```
if ($new_istf){
    print "\tdbug:: $res_dir/$line/$fub_name*.istf:\t'$new_istf'\n";
} else {
    print "\tdbug:: $res_dir/$line/$fub_name*.istf:\t''\n";
}
```

and the resulting output was:

```
    dbug:: RESULTS//791202_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791202_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791212_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791241_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791241_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791248_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791251_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791251_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791258_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791272_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791272_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791273_0_SA1/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791301_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791301_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791333_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791349_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791349_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791357_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791405_0_SA1/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791405_0_SA1/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791432_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791434_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791434_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791459_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791462_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791462_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791463_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
    dbug:: RESULTS//791467_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf:   'RESULTS//791467_0_SA0/ieuni5cts.mlc.xxx.x.istf'
    dbug:: RESULTS//791471_0_SA1/ieuni5cts*.istf:   ''
```

but all those files exist. since `glob` suppose to work like the sell interpreter, i've checked it and when I do `echo RESULTS//791463_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf` (and every other file that was not detected by `glob`, it gives the right file name.

I've also tried to run glob as a one liner with the paths that didn't give result, and it worked:

```
perl -e 'print glob("RESULTS//791467_0_SA0/ieuni5cts*.istf"),"\n"'
```

and it gave the right result as well

Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

---

> In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
>   expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such
>   filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

---

The code posted is in scalar context.

See if calling it in list context solves the issue:

```
my ( $new_istf ) = glob ( "$res_dir/$line/$fub_name*.istf" );
```